# Unequal length arrays while calculating paired tests

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have two dfs:

```
df1       and df2 
1              3
2              3
2              4
4              6
6              7
7              
9
```

I want to calculate Two-sample PAIRED t-test but I am unable to coz both the dfs don't have the same length.

I am using the `t, p = stat.ttest_rel(df1, df2)` method from scipy to calculate.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do a paired test?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. You either remove the pair(s) where one value is missing (which might introduce bias - especially in this case where only the high values in df1 are missing their pairs in df2) or you impute them (e.g., by using multiple imputation).

Comment: I agree with the answer in general (+1) but imho doing a significance test based on imputed values has little value.

Answer (score 0):

A paired t-test does not make much sense unless you have unequal numbers of observations. How about performing a regular t-test?

Comment: I do have unequal number of observations. The first df has 7 while the second has only 5.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try the **scipy.stats.ttest_rel**? in the [scipy API reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) we can see as description: "This is a test for the null hypothesis that two related or repeated samples have identical average (expected) values." and in [this page](https://machinelearningmastery.com/statistical-hypothesis-tests-in-python-cheat-sheet/) we see a good example.

i use in this way:

```
# import stats from scipy
import scipy.stats as stats

# define the vectors
df1 = df[df.payment_type == 1].fare_amount
df2 = df[df.payment_type == 2].fare_amount

#simply execute
t, p = stats.ttest_ind(df1, df2, alternative='two-sided')
```

That's works fine for me; some comment and corrections are always welcome